What configuration should be used to obfuscate Angular 18 project with javascript-obfuscator?
What configuration should be used to obfuscate Angular 18 project with javascript-obfuscator ?
I am using package.json
{
  "name": "angular.dev",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "NG_BUILD_PARALLEL_TS=0 ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --configuration production",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.0.0",
    "@aws-amplify/ui-angular": "^5.0.19",
    "aws-amplify": "^6.5.3",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/build": "^18.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^18.0.0",
    "javascript-obfuscator": "^4.1.1",
    "typescript": "~5.5.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}

with Angular 18, javascript-obfuscator version 4.1.1 and @angular-builders/custom-webpack version 18.0.0
My angular.json file is
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "first-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "inlineTemplate": true,
          "inlineStyle": true,
          "style": "scss",
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:class": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:guard": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:interceptor": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:resolver": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:service": {
          "skipTests": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack.config.js"
            },
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "outputPath": "dist/first-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kB",
                  "maximumError": "1MB"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kB",
                  "maximumError": "4kB"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular/build:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "first-app:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "first-app:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular/build:extract-i18n"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}

and webpack.config.js is
const JavaScriptObfuscator = require('javascript-obfuscator');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    plugins: [
  new JavaScriptObfuscator(
      {
       rotateStringArray: true,
       stringArray: true,
       stringArrayEncoding: ['rc4'],
       stringArrayThreshold: 0.75,
      },
      ['vendor.js']
  ),
 ],
};

when I am running this project with npm run build i am getting the error :
[error] ValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.plugins[12] misses the property 'apply'. Should be:
   function
   -> The run point of the plugin, required method.
    at validate (D:\code\temp\playground_0-hello-world\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:191:11)
    at validateSchema (D:\code\temp\playground_0-hello-world\node_modules\webpack\lib\validateSchema.js:78:2)
    at create (D:\code\temp\playground_0-hello-world\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:130:24)
    at webpack (D:\code\temp\playground_0-hello-world\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:182:32)
    at Object.f [as webpackFactory] (D:\code\temp\playground_0-hello-world\node_modules\webpack\lib\index.js:73:50)
    at createWebpack (D:\code\temp\playground_0-hello-world\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\builders\webpack\index.js:28:36)
    at runWebpack (D:\code\temp\playground_0-hello-world\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\builders\webpack\index.js:40:12)
    at D:\code\temp\playground_0-hello-world\node_modules\@angular-builders\custom-webpack\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\builders\browser\index.js:116:47
    at D:\code\temp\playground_0-hello-world\node_modules\rxjs\src\internal\operators\switchMap.ts:109:21
    at OperatorSubscriber._this._next (D:\code\temp\playground_0-hello-world\node_modules\rxjs\src\internal\operators\OperatorSubscriber.ts:70:13)


Can anyone suggest which package.json, angular.json and webpack.config.js configuration should be used to obfuscate Angular 18 project using javascript-obfuscator?
Are there any other options to obfuscate Angular 18 project code?

the right settigns for me are :
package.json
{
  "name": "angular.dev",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "NG_BUILD_PARALLEL_TS=0 ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --configuration production",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.0.0",
    "@aws-amplify/ui-angular": "^5.0.19",
    "aws-amplify": "^6.5.3",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/build": "^18.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^18.0.0",
    "javascript-obfuscator": "^4.1.1",
    "typescript": "~5.5.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-obfuscator": "^3.5.1"
  }
}

angular.json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "first-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "inlineTemplate": true,
          "inlineStyle": true,
          "style": "scss",
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:class": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:guard": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:interceptor": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:resolver": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:service": {
          "skipTests": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack.config.js",
              "mergeStrategies": {
                "module.rules": "prepend"
              }
            },
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "outputPath": "dist/first-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "1mb",
                  "maximumError": "1.5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kB",
                  "maximumError": "4kB"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular/build:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "first-app:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "first-app:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular/build:extract-i18n"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}

webpack.config.js
var WebpackObfuscator = require('webpack-obfuscator');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    plugins: [

        new WebpackObfuscator ({
            debugProtection: true
        }, ['vendor.js']) ]
};

